# How can i duplicate my firebase auntification into firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have got a project in react native, where needs to connec users id and his statistic in my app.
It's just an a firebase auth:[image]
i need to duplicate users in realtime db:[image]

How can i make it? My registraion user code:

```
  const hanldeRegister = () => {
    if (password  !== confirmPassword){
      alert("Пароли не совпадают!")
    }
    else{
      setIsLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp',
      params: {
        key: 'AIzaSyA-mqI2gljPLMS1KW_InAyE3XzS5tQch2I',
      },
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update',
          params: {
            key: 'AIzaSyA-mqI2gljPLMS1KW_InAyE3XzS5tQch2I',
          },
          data: {
            idToken: res.data.idToken,
            displayName: name + ' ' + surname
          }
        }).then((r) => {
          setUser({...r.data, idToken: res.data.idToken})
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e, 'updaate profile error');
          alert(e.message);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        })

        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.request._response))

    }
```

Comment: That sounds feasible. The Firebase APIs are quite well documented, so did you already give it a try yourself based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?

Comment: i take an exception like: FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)., js engine: hermes

Comment: I try it in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815390/when-i-trying-to-wirte-data-in-firebase-db-take-an-exception Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that react to the creation of a new user. Then, everytime the function is called (so, everytime a new user register itself), the function will add a new entry in your realtime database.

The function will look similar to this:

```
import { getFunctions } from "firebase/functions";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

const functions = getFunctions();

exports.createRealtimeDBUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const database = getDatabase();
  set(ref(db, user.id), {
    //ANYTHING YOU WANT TO SAVE
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, i haven't file in my project, just firebase.js . I make the auth by rest api to firebase

Comment: i take an exception like:  FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)., js engine: hermes

Comment: are you sure you're deploying it as a function? the error is related to hosting