# When i trying to wirte data in firebase db take an exception

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, api, firebase-realtime-database

I have got an a react native app, i need to save data in db with user's token. How can i do it?

It's my auth firebase:[image]
Also i need an a real time db to save here data and user's token:
[image]

I have a registration of user, and i know that i need here to make an a api into realtime db mthod PUT for url: https://[PROJECT ID]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/, but how can i do it i didn't know, pls help:

```
const hanldeRegister = () => {
    if (password  !== confirmPassword){
      alert("The passwords are different!")
    }
    else{
      setIsLoading(true)
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp',
      params: {
        key: 'A',
      },
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
        axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update',
          params: {
            key: 'A',
          },
          data: {
            idToken: res.data.idToken,
            displayName: name + ' ' + surname
          }
        }).then((r) => {
          setUser({...r.data, idToken: res.data.idToken})
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e, 'updaate profile error');
          alert(e.message);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.request._response))
    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to explain the process in great depth, because that would be reiterating the already existing docs.

Here is a link to the getting started docs regarding firestorage.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

You should also checkout the starting docs, in regards to setting up firebase with web.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Thi will guide you through the process of setting up and intergrading firebase with your JavaScript application.